# How to make the image size the same as the button size in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make the image size in 'background_normal'and background_down' the same as the button actual size, but it is not working. The actual button size without the image is bigger than the image when it is added.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout=GridLayout(cols=1)
        for i in range(6):
            btn = Button(size_hint=(.54,.12),pos_hint={'center_x':.5,'center_y':.5},background_normal='put_any.png,background_down='put_any.png)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
           
        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

When I run the code using my own image, the background_normal image on the button becomes small but when I remove the image from the background_normal and background_down, the button size is bigger than the image.  Please how do I fix this. I have tried increase the dimensions of the image itself before using it,but it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try using padx and pady then archor for the location

```
enter code here
 button = Button(root, text='red', command=lambda:click(0),padx=10).pack(anchor=S)
 button2 = Button(root, text='blue', command=lambda:click (1),padx=15).pack(anchor=S+E)
```

Comment: I don't understand any of the code above. please read my question again, it kivy and am using a for loop with background_normal

Comment: Owh my bad, didn't notice that, Also I cant comment thou it needs 50 reputation so thats why Im posting it in answer